# I don't like either X or Y vs. I don't like X or Y either

Tags: meaning, grammar, differences, word-usage

Do the following two sentences mean the same thing:

1. > I don't like either cherry juice or soda.
2. > I don't like cherry juice or soda either.

Although they both convey the idea that the speaker doesn't like cherry soda and also doesn't like soda, I don't think they are synonymous. While sentence 1 can be used as a standalone sentence, that emphasises that the speaker doesn't like both drinks, sentence 2 can only be used to agree with someone else who has expressed the same opinion. What are your thoughts?

Comment: I don't like orange juice or apple juice.  And I don't like cherry juice or soda either.  Bring me a beer!

Comment: That’s what ***neither ...nor*** is for:  *I like neither cherry juice nor soda.*   But I disagree that 2 can only be used to agree.  It can stand alone as a statement.

Comment: Sentence 2 does need some context.  It sounds like you've answered your own question about these sentences meaning the same thing.

Comment: @livresque - I take #2 to mean the same as: *I don’t like cherry juice or soda for that matter.*

Comment: What does require context is deciding whether it means “I don’t like cherry juice and I don’t like soda” or “I like neither cherry juice nor cherry soda”

Answer (score 2):

I don't like cherry juice or soda.................= a negative statement

I like neither cherry juice nor soda..............= a negative statement

I don't like either.................= a negative statement in response to a question 'Do you like cherry juice or soda?

I don't like cherry juice or soda either.............= as negative statement in agreement with someone who says they don't like cherry juice or soda

Comment: Synonymous with your fourth sentence: "Neither do I.".